# Port fowarding for RDP not working

Tags: networking, router, remote-desktop, firewall

I'm setting port fowarding in the router's web interface as follows

[image]

The device at 192.168.0.50 is being assigned this IP statically by the router.
Windows Firewall is also configured to allow remote desktop connections (port 3389)

[image]

However, when I try to connect, monitoring with wireshark shows that no traffic is received, and the client trying to connect timeouts. Where can the problem be? The router's firewalls are disabled, I even try disabling Windows Firewall, and still no packet is even received. Is it possible that the ISP is blocking port 3389?

Comment: Are you assigning static ip from the router? Or was it assigned on the pc?

Comment: Also, it's probably a good idea to turn all of those firewalls back on...

Comment: They are turned on, I just turned them off for testing. About the static ip, it's being statically asigned by the router